# iOS proximity & GPS measure the distance

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, proximity

I am developing an app where I require to alert user if he move more than 20 meters from his checking location. I am planning to use proximity sensor for this development. However I found this document.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

It says

> "The specific threshold distances are determined by the hardware and
> the location technologies that are currently available. For example,
> if Wi-Fi is disabled, region monitoring is significantly less
> accurate. However, for testing purposes, you can assume that the
> minimum distance is approximately 200 meters."

If I use GPS distance it will take considerable power utilization. Am I developing on wrong path? Appriciate your kind sugesstions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your task the only way is using GPS in best quality mode (`CLLocationAcuracyBest`).
Check loaction.getAcuracy() to see if the location came from GPS or cell Tower/wifi.

Comment: doesn't `loaction.getAcuracy()` just tell you the desiredAccuracy you set yourself?! Doesn't the OP want to know if info came from tower? Or is that certain accuracies only come from non-GPS data?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use GPS based on your needs. It will surely take some more power consumption but works with more accurately.Please be more specific how many times you need this function within app.

Comment: He already mentioned he needs update on every 20 meter covered.

Comment: But the thing is with this range (20 Meters), that hardware will not be so useful. GPS normally works with signal towers and practically they offen changes coordinates even if some times user did not change their position :D

Comment: In my app I successfully implemented where distance calculation of every 5 meters were done.

Comment: Why not help him then ? You are here to do so. You can calculate for 5 meters but how accurate that was let me know this ? Don't tell me what you have calculated in code. Apply for 1 meter but makes no sense when it will not work in actual device :P

Comment: I tested on device rigorously and it worked perfect. I used GPS for that.

Comment: Then please suggest him your way. It will perfect for him and no doubt with his requirement that will great to use your code sniff.

Comment: I am on windows machine and I need my mac to look what exactly I did, when I can access my mac I will get back here.

Comment: Let us see how much power his app will consume according to his needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. I am trying to do this without GPS.